# 404 after creating record in Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a resource called Professions where I've recently changed the column `ID` to `profession_id` because in the future I'll need a `hasMany` relationship.

**Model:**

```
class Profession extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'profession_id';
}
```

**In the Nova resource:**

```
public static $search = [
    'profession_id',
];
```

**In the migration file:**

```
$table->increments('profession_id');
```

I've ran `php artisan migrate:refresh` and all tables and columns are created correctly.

This is what happens:

- When I create a profession, after pressing the 'Create Profession' button in Nova I get a 404. The profession is created however.
- Listing, viewing and editing professions works fine

The weird thing is that if I edit a Profession and save it, it will go to the view page where the new Profession record is displayed. This is the exact same page where I should land if I press 'Create Profession', however that gives a 404.

I'm struggling here because the 404 doesn't give any info on where the error occurs.

Comment: Do the laravel logs contain any errors?

Comment: Nope. I just figured out that changing the column name is actually not necessary and creates this behaviour. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I interpreted from the documentation that I needed to rename all the `id` columns to include the resource name, eg `professions_id`.

It turns out that changing the column name is unnecessary, and actually creates this error. So leave them as `id`. Note that you can actually change column names, it's just that in this case (with Nova) it resulted in an error.

There was nothing to be found in the Laravel logs btw.